# max.poll.records vs batch.max.rows kafka. What is difference between two properties?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

**max.poll.records** vs **batch.max.rows** kafka. What is difference between these two properties?

I am using Kafka Sink Task to read records from Kafka topic. The put() in the SinkTask method is the entry point from where all records will be fetched. Currently, when the connector starts, it will fetch all records together which are not committed. I want the worker task to fetch a single record at a time. How to do it?
Which of the above properties should I put in the connector config file?

Answer (score 2):

**max.poll.records** is configuration property of `Kafka Consumer`:

> *max.poll.records*: The maximum number of records returned in a single call to `poll()`.

**batch.max.rows** is configuration property of `Kafka Jdbc Source Connector`:

> *batch.max.rows*: Maximum number of rows to include in a single batch when polling for new data. This setting can be used to limit the amount of data buffered internally in the connector.

---

So in your case, you cannot use the `batch.max.rows` property as inappropriate, but you can configure`batch.max.rows` with the `consumer` prefix:

```
consumer.max.poll.records=1
```